# Wordpress wp_link_pages show only next/prev link

Tags: pagination, wp-link-pages

I used nextpage to separate a post into multiple page and I don't want to show pagination as 1 2 3 Next, I want to to show **Prev Next**, below is the code I come up with after reading the wp link pages, it is still showing **1 2 3 Next**, I don't know what I did wrong, any help will be much appreciated

```
<?php
wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 
'previouspagelink'    => '', 'nextpagelink' => '<span>Next</span>', 
'next_or_number' => 'next' ) ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not working.
Did you try with the defaults but only changing the "page" and clearing the before/after?

```
wp_link_pages( array(
    'before'           => '',
    'after'            => '',
    'link_before'      => '',
    'link_after'       => '',
    'next_or_number'   => 'next',
    'separator'        => ' ',
    'nextpagelink'     => 'Next page',
    'previouspagelink' => 'Previous page',
    'pagelink'         => '%',
    'echo'             => 1
    )
);
```

---

Alternatively you could always "hard code" the links to the single.php.

I mean that doesn't really fix you issue, but you know..

```
<?php global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more;
if ( $multipage ) {
    if ( $more ) {
        $prev = $page - 1;
        if ( $prev ) {
            $link = _wp_link_page($prev).'Previous page</a>';
            $output .= apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_link', $link, $prev );
        }
        $next = $page + 1;
        if ( $next <= $numpages ) {
            if ( $prev ) {
                $output .= ' ';
            }
            $link = _wp_link_page($next).'Next page</a>';
            $output .= apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_link', $link, $next );
        }
    }
echo apply_filters('wp_link_pages', $output);
} ?>
```

Modified straight from [post-template.php/wp_link_pages()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0)

Comment: your code produced the same result **1 2 3 Next** I don't know what is wrong, been searching and testing with different parameters for hours now, no luck

Comment: It must be some filters in the theme that are overriding this, I will look into it. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah strange. Just tested myself with `<?php wp_link_pages(array('before'=> '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'next_or_number' => 'next')); ?>` on a test site and it's working fine and not outputting any numbers.